# Grid letters with rectangle OCR

Tags: vb.net, ocr

I have been trying to grid each letter with rectangle on an image (on that image there is only colors white and black). I've started like this:

```
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = Label1.Image
    Dim xmax As Integer
    Dim ymax As Integer
    xmax = Label1.Width - 1
    ymax = Label1.Height - 1
    Dim top, bottom, left, right As Integer
    Dim first As Boolean = True
    Dim last As Boolean = False
    Dim first2 As Boolean = True
    Dim last2 As Boolean = False

    Dim pen As Pen = Pens.Red

    For x = 0 To xmax

        For y = 0 To ymax
            With bmp.GetPixel(x, y)
                If .R = 0 And .G = 0 And .B = 0 And first = True Then
                    left = x 
                    first = False
                    last = True
                ElseIf .R = 0 And .G = 0 And .B = 0 And last = True Then
                    right = x 
                End If
            End With
        Next y
    Next x

    For y = 0 To ymax
        For x = 0 To xmax
            With bmp.GetPixel(x, y)
                If .R = 0 And .G = 0 And .B = 0 And first2 = True Then
                    top = y 
                    first2 = False
                    last2 = True
                ElseIf .R = 0 And .G = 0 And .B = 0 And last2 = True Then
                    bottom = y 
                End If
            End With
        Next x
    Next y
    first = True
    first2 = True
    last = False
    last2 = False
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(left, top, right - left, bottom - top)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect)
    Label1.Image = bmp
```

It'll check all of the pixels on the image and it'll get the black ones, I could draw rectangle around only one letter but I couldn't more then one at the time.
Still can't use it for seperate letters.

I'll be thankful for all of your responses.

Comment: So I see where you are finding pixels that are black... but then what? Is there more to your algorithm that you aren't showing us?

Comment: As you can see I have added much more to codes, if you try it it grids black letter images by red rectangle.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this with a sample of multiple letters over multiple lines and it drew a red box around all of them. You want a red box around each individual letter?